# Should we opt in for the special Hat Dash promo?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

## The haberdashery begins December 19.

---

Just recieved the following email from Stack Exchange, and wanted to know if you guys think we should participate:

> Last year, on our Gaming site, we hosted an event called [Hat Dash](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/), where users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear".
>
> For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora with pen) to the editor.  Examples:

[image: 2011 Hat Dash hats]

> This year, we're expanding the promotion to all sites which choose to participate, and redesigning the hat selection to be more appropriate to the entire network (no severed Wampa heads). Some of it is holiday-themed, some of it is a bit silly, and all of it is (hopefully) fun!

Note: Users who don't want to see the hats will be able to opt-out by clicking an "I hate hats" link.

Note 2: text stolen from [SFF](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2415/3267)

Note 3: My presentation of the yes/no voting options is in no way meant to discourage further discussion. If you want to say anything (preferably more-or-less on-topic) please do! If you just want to vote (or not), the options are there for you.

Comment: As a general rule, it is typically better to open the topic to discussion rather than polling with this type of *"everyone vote on **my** choices"* format. Anyone who cares to chime in should have a voice. Generally you should be able to infer from the conversation and voting what the community wants. Just my opinion. It's not like we're deciding the fate of mankind here, but [polling is not a substitute for discussion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Polling_is_not_a_substitute_for_discussion)

Comment: Where are the hats this year???

Comment: @bashophil They're on main.

Comment: @bashophil [the blog post announcing the start](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/winter-bash-2013-is-here/)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, hats are cool. Let's do it!

Comment: We've voted - when do we get hats? ;)

Comment: I've just sent the email opting us in, so the event starts Dec 19.

Comment: Awesome! I look forward to it...

Answer (score -5):

No, we don't need no stinkin' hats!