# Do we want hats this year?

Tags: discussion

As some of you may remember, SE has a bit of an event every winter, the Hat Dash. We had unanimous support last year, but I thought I'd ask again just in case anyone has any objections. Unless there's a consensus against before December 1st, we're in.

Background / last year's question:

[Should we opt in for the special Hat Dash promo?](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/q/302/18)

Comment: YES! Obvs...........

Comment: In short? Ab-so-lute-ly!

Answer (score 5):

Of course we need hats! Hats are

- fashionable

[image]

- a shelter against the elements and necessary to survive a harsh winter

[image]

- yummy

[image]

- they rock

[image]

- just WTF I have no idea?!?!

[image]
[image]

Comment: ROFL dude, second last one is hilarious :D